# How to connect socket.io inside docker-compose between containers

Tags: docker, websocket, socket.io, docker-compose

I have one container that is serving http on port 4000.
it has socket server attached

docker-compose:

```
  dashboard-server:
    image: enginetonic:compose1.2
    container_name: dashboard-server
    command: node src/service/endpoint/dashboard/dashboard-server/dashboard-server.js
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 4000:4000

  integration-test:
    image: enginetonic:compose1.2
    container_name: integration-test
testRegex "(/integration/.*|(\\.|/)(integration))\\.jsx?$$"
    tty: true
```

server:

```
const http = require('http').createServer(handler)
const io = Io(http)
io.on('connection', socket => {
  logger.debug('socket connected')
})

io.use((socket, next) => {
  logger.debug('socket connection established.')
})

http.listen(4000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log(
      `Server running at http://127.0.0.1:4000/`
    )
```

output in docker:

`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:4000/`

`https is listening: true`

Now, I am trying to connect to this server from another container like this:

file:

```
  const url = `ws://dashboard-server:4000`

      const ioc = IoC.connect(url)

      ioc.on('error', error => {
        console.log(error.message)
      })
      ioc.on('connect', res => {
        console.log('connect')
      })
      ioc.on('connect_error', (error) => {
        console.log(error.message)
      })
```

output:

`xhr poll error`

When I run both locally in terminal, I get correct response

`{"message":"socket connection established","level":"debug"}`

Why isnt socket making connection inside container, but locally it is? 
What am I doing wrong?

edit: only part of files are displayed for readability. socket connects normaly on local machine with with spawning both files in separate terminals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to link the docker containers and refer to them by name, not `127.0.0.1`.  https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking provides more doc.  You'll also need to listen to '0.0.0.0' so that you accept connections across the docker network.

I only see one container in your compose file.  If you're trying to connect to the docker containers from *outside* docker, you'll have to expose a port.  The same reference shows you how.

```
http.listen(4000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
```

should become

```
http.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
```

so that the server is listening on all addresses, including the address that docker is automatically allocating on a docker network.

Then the client has to refer to the server by the name given in docker compose, so

```
const url = `ws://127.0.0.1:4000`
```

becomes

```
const url = `ws://dashboard-server:4000`
```

Comment: you have two parts of docker-compose, now let me check this networking

Comment: here, I merged them together. Can you make now code example how to link them, please?

Comment: also your url is invalid :)

Comment: oops, missing `g`.  Fixed.  Also added some more example for you.

Comment: oh, I didnt change listening to 0.0.0.0