# socket.io server not working in docker-compose environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, socket.io

I'm creating a website using vite/React for the frontend and socket.io for the backend server in two separate docker containers, and I have an issue, I can't connect to the socket.io server, I get this error: `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:6666/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket.`
I manage my containers using docker-compose, I use the right port in my socket.io server and the frontend and backend containers are in the same docker network.
Here is my docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      PORT: ${BACK_PORT}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
    ports:
      - ${BACK_PORT}:${BACK_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - ./shared_types:/app/src/shared_types
    networks:
      - all
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: sh start.sh

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    image: node:lts-alpine
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      PORT: ${FRONT_PORT}
      VITE_BACK_PORT: ${BACK_PORT}
    ports:
      - ${FRONT_PORT}:${FRONT_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - ./shared_types:/app/src/shared_types
    networks:
      - all
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: sh start.sh

networks:
  all:
    driver: bridge
```

The backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm i -g npm@latest

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

the .env file:

```
BACK_PORT=6666
FRONT_PORT=8080
JWT_SECRET=ilovecandies
```

and I have a basic socket.io server like this:

```js
import type { ServerOptions, Socket } from './types/server';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import http from 'http';
import { SignJWT, jwtVerify } from 'jose';
import express from 'express';

const createServerOptions = (options?: Partial<ServerOptions>): ServerOptions => {
  return {
    port: 3000,
    ...options,
  };
};

export const createServer = (options?: Partial<ServerOptions>) => {
  const serverOptions = createServerOptions(options);
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  const server: Socket = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    },
    transports: ['websocket'],
  });
  const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.JWT_SECRET!);

  server.on('connection', async socket => {
    console.log(`Client ${socket.id} connected!`);

    const verify = await jwtVerify(socket.handshake.auth.token, secret);

    console.log(verify);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log(`Client ${socket.id} disconnected!`);
    });
  });

  return {
    start: () => {
      console.log(`Server: listening on port ${serverOptions.port}.`);
      server.listen(serverOptions.port);
    }
  };
};
```

and the main.ts:

```js
import { createServer } from './server';

(() => {
  const server = createServer({
    port: +process.env.PORT!,
  });
  server.start();
})();
```

(The `Socket` type is a custom socket.io `Server` with custom events map)

and in my frontend, when I'm trying to connect like this:

```js
const socket = io(`http://localhost:${import.meta.env.VITE_BACK_PORT!}`, {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  reconnection: false,
  auth: {
    token:
      document.cookie
        .split("; ")
        .find(x => x.startsWith("snet-token="))
        ?.split("=")[1] ?? "",
  },
});
```

It doesn't work, I don't know why. Instead of `localhost` I also tried `0.0.0.0`, and `backend`, and I also tried everything without the `http://` prefix, but none of that worked.

Comment: `localhost` is referring to the container it is running in. In your case the frontend container ...

Comment: Typically, containers should be able to reach each other using their service's name. Can you connect to the backend from the host? This should be able via `ws://localhost:6666

Comment: From the host ? you mean from outside the docker containers ? no I didn't try yet, but I tried inside my frontend container to connect using the service name (backend), neither this or localhost/0.0.0.0 worked

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean, because if that's not possible, then there is something wrong inside of your container ...

Comment: @derpirscher I'll try this later because I don't have access to my computer right now, but I think it is rather an issue with vite than an issue with the backend container itself

Comment: All I can think of now is that you need to add host: 0.0.0.0 to serveroptions.

Answer (score 3):

When running applications in Docker containers, especially when using Docker Compose, containers do not know each other by `localhost`. They are aware of each other by their service names [defined in `docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#service-configuration-reference).

Try and replace the use of `localhost` in your frontend code, if it runs in a container:

```js
const socket = io(`http://backend:${import.meta.env.VITE_BACK_PORT!}`, { ... });
```

Again, this assumes your frontend is running inside a container, and it tries to access the backend container.

Make sure both frontend and backend are on the same network. Based on your `docker-compose.yml`, they are, but it is always good to double-check with:

```
docker network inspect [NETWORK_NAME]
```

Replace `[NETWORK_NAME]` with your network name, which should be the folder's name followed by `_all` in your case, unless you changed the folder's name.

And check your CORS configurations on the backend does allow the frontend to connect. For the sake of debugging, you have set `origin: '*'` which should technically allow any origin, but once you have fixed the issue, you should restrict it to only the frontend's domain or IP for security reasons.

---

Note: if your frontend code runs in the browser, then `localhost` refers to the machine where the browser is running, not the Docker container. Meaning, if you are accessing the frontend from the browser on your host machine, the `localhost` correctly refers to the host machine indeed, not the container.
Therefore, to access the backend (which is in a container), you would indeed use `localhost:6666` as your address, assuming your port mapping (`6666:6666`) is set correctly in your `docker-compose.yml`.

```js
const socket = io(`http://localhost:6666`, {
    transports: ["websocket"],
    reconnection: false,
    auth: {
        token: document.cookie.split("; ").find(x => x.startsWith("snet-token="))?.split("=")[1] ?? "",
    },
});
```

But make sure you have set the environment variable correctly in Vite's environment. If you are using the development environment, the environment variable should be in a [file named `env.dev`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71923917/6309) (if that is how you have set up Vite, see "[Env Variables and Modes](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) ") or simply in the `.env` file.

---

> I partially resolved the problem, when removing `transports=["websocket"]` from both the server and the client it works, now I need to figure out why websockets aren't working

If the removal of the `transports: ["websocket"]` option fixed the connection, then the issue is likely related to the WebSocket initialization or configuration.

WebSockets start as regular HTTP requests with headers asking the server to upgrade to WebSockets. If something is not correctly handling this upgrade request, it could lead to problems. In some environments, like certain proxy settings or web servers, this upgrade request might be denied or not processed properly, as seen [in this issue](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/112#issuecomment-1274196220).

If you are using any middleware in your Express server or a router, make sure they are not interfering with the WebSocket upgrade requests.

And make sure any CORS settings on your backend are correctly configured. While you have added `origin: '*'` which should allow all origins, double-check if there are other security or header settings interfering.

Comment: I said at the end that I also tried http://backend:6666 but none of this seems to be working (I also checked the env and it works, when expanding VITE_BACK_PORT I correctly get 6666, or else the error message wouldnt expand the port)

Comment: @Fayeure Just to be sure: is your frontend running directly on your host? Or in a container?

Comment: my frontend is running in a docker container (the frontend container in my docker-compose.yml)

Comment: @Fayeure OK, so no localhost for you then. Is there a container named backend? And is "backend" a reference published on your DNS? Note: using network: host is good for development/testing, not recommended for production.

Answer (score 0):

The frontend code you posted is running in the browser as far as I can see:

```
  const socket = io(`http://localhost:${import.meta.env.VITE_BACK_PORT!}`, {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  reconnection: false,
  auth: {
    token:
      document.cookie
        .split("; ")
        .find(x => x.startsWith("snet-token="))
        ?.split("=")[1] ?? "",
  },
});
```

But your browser does not eun within the docker container. Which means that it cannot resolve `VITE_BACK_PORT`.

Chnage it to

```
  const socket = io(`http://localhost:6666...
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: Should be getting it from his .env file, VITE_ prefixed variables work this way in Vite dev environment https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html - it could well be that he hasn't got an {environmentname}.env (judging from the npm command it would be 'dev.env' but hard to tell without seeing his npm config) file which would be necessary too I think.

Comment: The problem doesn't come from the env, it gets expanded to 6666, I checked it (or else the error message wouldnt be `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:6666/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket.`

Comment: See this link about exposing the server port: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895365/how-to-connect-socket-io-inside-docker-compose-between-containers.

Comment: Okay that's pretty handy rom vite. Really should look into it more. Thanks for explaining @razethestray

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
network_mode: "host"
```

in your docker-compose.yml to access via localhost. In bridge mode it can't access localhost.

Comment: Yes but I want to access it via the service name (backend), but it doesn't work either, I'll still try doing that for testing

Answer (score 0):

I partially resolved the problem, when removing `transports=["websocket"]` from both the server and the client it works, now I need to figure out why websockets aren't working

Comment: OK, I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76909032/6309) with suggestions for your websockets.